# Setting a computed property that is an array

Tags: ember.js

Is a way to set a computed property that returns an array? In the following example the get function gets called but never the set function when new participants ids are added/removed

```
participantIds: computed({
    get() {
        Ember.debug('Getting...');
        return this.get('participants').mapBy('id');
    },
    set(key, participantIds) {
        Ember.debug('Setting...');
        // do something when participants ids changed
        return participantIds;
    }
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because the computed property itself is not modified, but the *Array you returned* is modified.

What you want *could* be done with an [ArrayProxy](https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy.html), but I wouldn't recommend this.

Its probably better to refactor in a way that you don't need this.